# How to add operation to Token in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am using a `MultiInput` control to which I am adding Tokens based on input from the user. For this I have used `addValidator` function to add Token with '*key*' and '*text*'.

I am looking to add operator (like '*EQ*') along with this data to the Token. I found `customData` aggregation for `sap.m.Token` control. Can this be used to add operations to the Token along with the key and text fields?

Below code does not work:

```
return new Token({
    customData: [{
        key: "range",
        value: {
            exclude: false,
            keyField: "LabelKey",
            operation: "EQ",
            value1: "sometext",
            value2: null

        }

    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add a Token with '*EQ*' operation in the following manner.

('*text*' is the value entered by user in the `MultiInput` control retrieved using the parameters of `addValidator` function to the `MultiInput` control)

```
return new Token({
        key: "range_0",
        text: "=" + text
    }).data("range", {
                        "exclude": false,
                        "operation": ValueHelpRangeOperation.EQ,
                        "keyField": "ProductId",
                        "value1": text,
                        "value2": ""
                    });
```

before which I had to define:

```
var ValueHelpRangeOperation = compLibrary.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpRangeOperation;
```

where compLibrary is '`sap/ui/comp/library`'